# Python: what happens to memory when deleting a list element?

Tags: python, list, memory-management, del

As for storing a list, Python seems to store a list of references to the list elements in a consecutive space in the memory. When I delete one element, e.g., `del[5]`, does Python move all references after the deleted one one slot ahead in the memory?

Comment: This is implementation-dependent and thinking at a level that doesn't really make sense for Python. Wondering about this will not help you write better Python code.

Comment: I'm exactly asking about the implementation idea here, but want a more efficient way to get the answer than diving into the source code. My purpose is also not for writing better Python code, but for curiosity and getting some intelligent ideas behind Python.

Comment: Your idea is absolutely correct. List is a consecutive sequence of references and if one is removed, the following references must be shifted. Thus, you can easily access an element of the list directly via a index. Pretty much all languages has a concept like this. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array for more.

Answer (score 0):

`del` on python list work as a slice function, where it can slice sublist from a list or remove the entire list.

After the `del` operation list references are updated.

For more info read this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement)